# Modelling users similar to airbnb and ebay

Tags: database-design

I am planning to implement a system similar to Airbnb where one registered user can post accommodation as well as book accommodation. Or in Ebay terms one registered user can post items as a seller but she would also like to purchase other items while being logged in with the same details.
Now I was thinking of to possible ways of doing this:

1. Each user to be given an attribute that would hold its status as either buyer or seller. The problem then, if I want the user to also buy but she was given the initial status of seller then how would enable this user to be buyer at that point?
2. I would create a parent class User which will hold all general details for a user (name, addres, etc.) and then subclass User into Buyer (or RentingPerson in Airbnb) and a separate Seller (or Landlord in Airbnb). And have in my DB three tables for these three categories. The problem then, if a user was registered as Buyer (inheriting from User) then how can also be a Buyer?

Which way would be easier? And how would you represent that diagrammatically?
Or is there a better way?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In such cases I use KISS approach :)

The user can be buyer, seller or both depending on what roles he has assigned. So, technically, all users can be both at any time, but you "hide" parts of the application they don't have the rights for.

So, what you need is a set of roles to separate Unregistered, Sellers, Buyers, Both, etc. in the application. This way you can easily switch between modes (you become a buyer when you enter your credit card, you become a seller when you verify your business address and credit card, etc).